# PCRE2 - Match every word whose suffix matches a backreference

Tags: regex, pcre, backreference

Given the string below,

```
ay bee ceefooh deefoo38 ee 37 ef gee38 aitch 38 eye19 jay38 kay 99 el88 em38 en 29 ou38 38 pee 12 q38 arr 999 esss 555
```

the goal is to match every word such that the suffix is a number that matches the number that appears after `foo` (which happens to be 38 in this case).

There is only one substring that begins with `foo` and ends with a number. The expected matches all exist after said substring.

Expected matches:

```
gee38
jay38
em38
ou38
q38
```

I've tried `foo(\d+).*?(\w+\1)\b` and `foo(\d+).*(\w+\1)\b`, but they fail to match all, because they either match the first one (`gee38`) or the last one (`q38`).

Is it possible to match all with just a single regex and, importantly, in just a single run?

The PCRE2 engine that I use behaves in the same way as https://regex101.com/r/uFEDOE/1. So, if the regex can match multiple substrings on regex101, then the engine that I use can too.

Comment: Would you always have "foo" as the first word having this suffix? Or can there be instances having this suffix *before* the word ending in "foo"?

Comment: @JvdV Only the substring that begins with "foo" and ends with a number determines the suffix. There is only one instance of such a substring. No other substring can determine the suffix.

Comment: Can the string also be `em38 foo38 q38` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird All except `foo38`. See the expected matches above. Having said that, I'll also accept a solution that can match `foo38` in addition to the expected matches above.

Comment: @NikoGambt I mean can the expected matches only occur after foo38? Or can they also occur before foo38 and do you also want to match those if there are any?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Only after `foo38`. Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, would be interesting to see if you can come up with something. I hit a wall here =). My 1st thought is it's not possible in a single run.

Comment: @JvdV Interesting question, I am also not sure if you can do that in a single run.

Comment: May be this regex could help: ``(?:foo|\G(?!^))(\d+).*?(?=(\w+))\w+(?=\1\b)``

Comment: @Michail That is brilliant, you could post that. I think if you add a word boundary after the non greedy match, and use the backreference in the lookahead you can reduce the number of steps.`(?:foo|\G(?!^))(\d+).*?\b(?=(\w+\1))\w+(?=\1)` https://regex101.com/r/T8dmDq/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Your regex is about x2 faster and it's great. Unfortunately I don't sure things like ``ab38cd`` are legal output

Comment: @Michail I see :-) I was impressed by your solution and I was fiddeling around with it to see how it works. Still +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?:foo|\G(?!^))(\d+).*?(?=(\w+))\w+(?=\1\b)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QyK4zj/1)

It could be some size or performance optimization.

@Niko Gambt, say if any optimization is important for you.

Comment: wow... didn't think it was possible! Thank you! Regarding optimisation, it can sometimes be useful because I often process large amount of serialised data.

Comment: Performance can be increased by about 1,5 times if you add ``\b`` after ``.*?`` as @Thefourthbird greatly suggest: ``(?:foo|\G(?!^))(\d+).*?\b(?=(\w+))\w+(?=\1\b)``

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)|foo)(\d++).*?\b(?=([a-z]++\1))[a-z]++(?=\1)` this improves it a bit more

Comment: Yes. And may be we can replace ``(?:\G(?!^)|foo)`` with ``\G(?(?=^).*?foo)``

Comment: Btw, is there a name for your technique? I'll call it "chaining" or "Michail's Chaining" :p

Comment: Turns out ommitting `\G` works too: `(?(?=^).*?foo)(\d++).*?\b(?=([a-z]++\1))[a-z]++(?=\1)`

Comment: Awesome! And for symmetry of omitting we can remove last ``(?=\1)``

Comment: `(?(?=^).*?foo)(\d++).*?\b(?=([a-z]++\1))[a-z]++` Hah! `(?(?=^)regex)` pretty much makes `\G` pointless cause it's much faster than `(regex|\G)` and `(\G(?!^)|regex)`.